# "Missing master key" using lockbox

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using [Lockbox](https://github.com/ankane/lockbox) to encrypt an attribute. But calling `valid?` always results in "Missing master key".

The master key is specified in `credentials.yml.enc` as `lockbox_master_key: <redacted>`. config/initializers/lockbox.rb specifies `Lockbox.master_key = Rails.application.credentials.lockbox_master_key`.

My model looks like:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :line_one
  blind_index :line_one
  ...
```

I appreciate any pointers on what is causing the exception.

Note: I have tried `puts`ing `Lockbox.master_key` and it prints the correct decrypted value.

Comment: Maybe do a `bundle open lockbox` and add some debug code to this line https://github.com/ankane/lockbox/blob/6c1e9a53f9c4a5480352fbafeed3c25f1c30bd57/lib/lockbox.rb#L82

Comment: Nice suggestion @Christian Bruckmayer. The control does not come to that line but continues to throw the exception. The exception does not occur if `blind_index :line_one` is removed. So it has something to do with that line.

Comment: Got the same error for a different reason: I failed to notice that my `rails credentials:edit` command didn't wait for edit and stored a blank file. 

`rails credentials:show -e test` helped me figure it out, plus using `EDITOR='code -nw' rails credentials:edit -e test`

Answer (score 3):

I didn't realize blind_index was a separate library needing its own separate configuration. Once configured (based on directions [here](https://github.com/ankane/blind_index#key-generation)), the issue is resolved.

Comment: Just fyi, with Blind Index 2.0+, a separate master key isn't needed when you use it with Lockbox.